# Dragging UIView with UIAttachmentBehavior and auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uikit-dynamics

I have a `UIScrollView` set up in IB with auto layout that contains an `UIImageView`. You can have a look at the Github repository of Evgenii to see how it is set up: https://github.com/evgenyneu/ios-imagescroll

The scrollview is used to enable pinch-to-zoom. I want to be able to move the scrollview around with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` using the new `UIAttachmentBehavior`. This works well without auto layout, but with auto layout enabled the scroll view content flickers and the scroll view gets distorted.

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint p = [_panGesture locationInView:self.view];

    if (_panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        CGPoint center = self.view.center;
        UIOffset offset = UIOffsetMake(p.x - center.x, p.y - center.y);

        _attachBehavior = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.scrollView offsetFromCenter:offset attachedToAnchor:p];
        [_animator addBehavior:_attachBehavior];
    } else if (_panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        _attachBehavior.anchorPoint = p;
    }
}
```

My guess is that the constraints set to the scroll- and imageViews interfere with the attachment behavior, also the `contentSize` of the scrollView depends on its content and the constraints of that.

Any idea how to get that working would be appreciated.

Edit: Tested with a normal view instead of the scrollView/imageView combination and the same problem exists. So it has to be an issue with using `UIAttachmentBehavior` for the panning purpose with auto layout.

Comment: You can use them together (for example https://github.com/whilethis/UIKit-Dynamics-101), not sure about the `UIAttachmentBehavior` though.

Comment: Yeah not with attachments, I had issues with this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use autolayout and UIKit Dynamics at the same time.  Both systems independently try to set the view's frame and they don't know about each other so that's why you see flickering.

My suggestion is to not use autolayout in this case.  If you really want to use it, you'll need to disable the constraints before enabling the dynamics animator and then re-enable them once the dynamics animation ends.

Comment: I spent 1 hours searching what goes wrong with UIKit Dynamics on my projects...
You confirm what I just realised !